# djangocms: move data from deprecated cmsplugin-filer-*-plugins to djangocms-*-plugins

Tags: django, migration, django-cms

Since the [cmsplugin-filer-*-plugins are deprecated](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/topics/commonly_used_plugins.html#deprecated-addons) with django-cms 3.5, I need a way to keep my plugins with moving them to the [newer djangocms-*-plugins](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/topics/commonly_used_plugins.html#django-cms-core-addons).

I am using the cmsplugin-filer plugins [FilerFile](https://github.com/divio/cmsplugin-filer/tree/develop/cmsplugin_filer_file), [FilerFolder](https://github.com/divio/cmsplugin-filer/tree/develop/cmsplugin_filer_folder) and [FilerImage](https://github.com/divio/cmsplugin-filer/tree/develop/cmsplugin_filer_image). Also I got a custom plugin which inherits from FilerImage.
I need to move those to the newer [djangocms-file-file, djangocms-file-folder](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file) and [djangocms-picture](http://djangocms-picture) without losing my plugins / data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time working on a migration I came to this solution:
https://gist.github.com/wfehr/86ac31e8e263b872b746cc721662251e

The gist provides a migration to move the data between the said third-party-apps and keep alls the plugins/data and change them to the supported ones.

I hope this will help someone facing the same problems:)

(The migration code itself may not be the perfect solution, but it gets the job done)

EDIT:

The linked migration can be used in any application of yours. Just put it in there as the next following migration, for example you have already "0011_added_new_model.py", then put in the file as "0012_filer_deprecation_move.py".
Then you have to add the migration 0011 in the dependencies, as seen in other (default) migrations.

TLDR: The above migration is a single, standalone migration. It is called as any other migration with `python manage.py migrate [app] [migration]` and you can put it in "any" app you want (where it makes the most sense to you).

Comment: Can you add a bot more Information on how to use your migration code? Where do I put the file and do I call it with `manage.py migrate something`? Or do I need to create a app solely for this purpose?